# Upgrading from 2.9.4 to 3.0.x and with a custom theme

Tags: themes, upgrade

I have a site where the Theme is VERY custom and I can no longer work with the developer.

Should I be worried about the theme no longer working in 3.0.4. and if so what is the easiest way for me to test my theme before upgrading?

Thanks

eric

Comment: Have you setup a local installation before? ie. setup a local running sever? This is a must do thing for any professional or amateur developer(it acts as your testing environment). If you've not done that before, check out: http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html (it's basically like running a website/server, just direct from your own computer)

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple steps to verify it!

1. Install [WP DB-Backup](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-db-backup/) in your 2.9.4 version.
2. Backup the DB
3. Setup a test server with Wordpress 3.0.4
4. Install WP-DB-Backup and restore from your previous backup
5. Test your theme

Comment: Thanks but to set up a test server don't I have to change a lot of the links and won't that effect the results in and of itself. I'm a bit of a newbe to WP and have never set up a WP server. So that has me a bit concerned as well... any thoughts?

Comment: @eric  Here's a link to SixRevisions.  This article http://bit.ly/eSvz0V shows the process of setting up a local development server which will allow you to test in the current version of Wordpress

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to test is to not bother with a DB backup and restore or another server. Install 3.0.4 in a subfolder like /wordpress304/ and use a different database prefix like wp304_, because you're using the same DB as the first install. Test the theme. If it works, update the first install to 3.0.4 and delete the subfolder install and the database tables it used. If it doesn't work, you have a way to fix the code before using it live.

Comment: Thanks Songdogtech... but you lost me a bit (as I stated earlier I'm a bit of a newbe to WP). DO you mean I should copy the entire design to a subfolder and update that copy to 3.0.4? and then just change the page links in that copy? Hate to sound like a total "tool" but while I can design a complete network and secure almost any OS... This is so new to me and it's my daughters site I just don't want to mess it up. Thanks again!

Comment: No, install a separate WP 3.0.4 site in a subfolder of your current site and use a new database prefix so you don't overwrite the current 2.9.4 site DB tables. Then copy only the theme you are testing to the 3.0.4 install, not everything. Use a privacy plugin like Absolute Privacy to keep the 3.0.4 site hidden while you work on the theme.

Comment: Do you know of any links that will give me a little direction?

Comment: Install WP the usual way in a /folder/ rather than in root of your host where the existing WP is already installed. Copy your wp-config.php to that folder and change the database prefix before running /folder/wp-admin/install.php from wp_ to wp304_ so you don't erase the existing tables for the current site. Or, as pointed out by t31os use Bitnami or XAMPP on your own PC or Mac to test the theme and hen you don't have to install WP a second time at your host.